# Testing unpickled dictionary in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm using `cPickle` to store a dictionary whose items are clustering objects from `sklearn.cluster` that do k-means clustering. The dictionary I get when unpickling looks fine and seems to work. However, when I compare it for equality against the input dictionary, it evaluates as `False`.

```
amino_acid = 'ILE'
clusterers = {'2 ILE_chi1': MiniBatchKMeans(...),
              '2 ILE_chi2': MiniBatchKMeans(...)}
output = open(''.join([amino_acid, '.pkl']), 'wb')
cPickle.dump(clusterers, output, -1)
output.close()
# Test that we can unpickle it.
input = open(''.join([amino_acid, '.pkl']), 'rb')
unpickled = cPickle.load(input)
print type(unpickled)
if clusterers == unpickled:
    print "Pickled successfully."
    print clusterers
else:
    print "Didn't pickle."
    print unpickled
    print clusterers
    print type(unpickled['2 ILE_chi1'])
    print unpickled.keys() == clusterers.keys()
    print unpickled.values() == clusterers.values()
input.close()
```

Corresponding output:

```
Didn't pickle.
{'2 ILE_chi1': MiniBatchKMeans(...), '2 ILE_chi2': MiniBatchKMeans(...)}
{'2 ILE_chi1': MiniBatchKMeans(...), '2 ILE_chi2': MiniBatchKMeans(...)}
<class 'sklearn.cluster.k_means_.MiniBatchKMeans'>
True
False
```

Does anyone know why the `MiniBatchKMeans` instances aren't equal? The [relevant page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) isn't very helpful on this particular matter. I can take a look at the `sklearn` source, but it inherits from multiple classes and I wondered if someone here might be able to to explain more quickly.

Comment: What happens if you compare them by simply saying `unpickled == clusterers`? The keys and values of them could be returned in any order, so it's difficult to compare them using those 2 methods.

Comment: Sorry, I included that in the first iteration. They don't compare equal. I think my problem might be what Tom Dalton suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects don't compare equal unless someone explicitly adds **eq** (or similar) methods on them:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, thing):
...         self.thing = thing

>>> b = A(1)
>>> c = A(1)
>>> b == c
False
```

If you create 2 copies of the same thing (MiniBatchKMeans in this case), without pickling them, do they compare equal? If so then you might want to raise a bug with scikit. If not then you might want to raise a feature request with scikit!

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. A copy generated with `copy.deepcopy` doesn't evaluate as equal. I might raise a feature request, but I'm not sure that there is much of a use case beyond "I'm paranoid and this is some of my PhD data".

I'll accept when SO lets me (in 3 minutes...).

Comment: I didn't just re-run the algorithm, in case there might be some stochasticity.